# Align elements in list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get values from database. When I print;I get below sequence

```
- ('Total Row(s):', 4)
- [202]
- [226]
- [561]
- [23]
```

But I need them to convert in list such as `list = [202,226,561,23]` but I   am unable to get this. All elements are showing on 0th position.
    Can someone please help me?`

This is my code and I am connecting with mysql I am connecting with mysql:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='examplecom',
                               database='niya')                 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        old_Value = raw_input("Please enter old Pincode: ")
        print "Pincode is entered by you is : %s" % old_Value
        query_Value = ("select `id`,`type_id`,"
                       "mappings`.`facility_id`,"
                       "mappings`.`service_area_id` from `service_areas`,"
                       "`mappings` where mappings`.`service_area_id`=`id` "
                       "and `type_id`='{0}'".format(old_Value))           
        cursor.execute(query_Value, )
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print('Total Row(s):', cursor.rowcount)
        for row in rows:
            list_Id = [];
            facility_Id = int(row[2])
            list_Id.append(facility_Id)
            print list_Id
```

Comment: i would assume something like `l = [x[0] for x in database]` would probably work but i cant really be sure without know what kind of database it actually is

Comment: Have added code. but it has become monster while pasting.  can you please help?

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks Mike for code refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
for row in rows:
    list_Id = [];
    facility_Id = int(row[2])
    list_Id.append(facility_Id)
    print list_Id
```

into:

```
list_Id = []
for row in rows:
    facility_Id = int(row[2])
    list_Id.append(facility_Id)
print list_Id
```

You made a new list for each row but want one list with all IDs, i.e. all rows.